# A function that relies on a variable outside its scope causes memory leak in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, memory

Consider the following code that creates a list of buttons that are attached to a point in a web map.

Initially I thought about extending element and adding the point as a property, but since that isn't [recommended](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom), I just went with referencing the object in the event function.

```
 pointsInMap = [
    {
      x : 20.2,
      y : 15.2,
      name : "point1"
    },
    {
      x : 20.2,
      y : 15.2,
      name : "point2"
    },
    {
      x : 20.2,
      y : 15.2,
      name : "point3"
    }
  ]

  function addZoomToButtons(points){
    points.forEach( point => {
      const button = document.createElement('button');
      button.text = `Zoom to ${point.name}`;
      //I'm overwriting this variable 3 times but javascript needs to keep reference to it, where will it be stored since it's outside the event scope?
      const pointObj = new Point(point.x, point.y)
      button.addEventListener( () => {
        myMap.panAndZoomToPoint(pointObj)
      })
      document.body.appendChild(button);
    })
  }

  addZoomtoButtons(pointsInMap);
```

Is there anything "wrong" with the code above in terms of performance/memory? I feel like there is but I don't know enough about memory management in Javascript to figure it out.

If there isn't anything wrong please help me understand why.

In my point of view, instead of just adding to memory 3 `events`, it will also keep 3 "copies" of the `addZoomToButtons`/`forEach` function scope since the it has variables that the `events` require.
This is just a small example, but please consider that things can get really big.

The code calls `const pointObj = new Point(point.x, point.y)` outside the event scope 3 times, but it can't just overwrite `pointObj` because the event references it, it also can't just shift the scope to be inside the event, so I'm assuming the scope imediately outside the event is also being stored unnecesarily.

If there is something wrong what's another way to design the solution?

Another way to word this question is how to bind object references to an event in a proper and recommended way?

Comment: First of all javascript does not often keep copies of anything. It does however keep references to things. I'm unclear why you think the above code would ever keep "copies" of the `addZoomToButtons` function. Each event handler will have a reference to a `Point`.

Comment: @gforce301 because I have 3 pointObj variables that are instantiated outside the event, in which scope will they be stored considering they have the same name? It makes no sense to me that javascript would shift their scope to sit inside the event

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does something not work?

Comment: @Pointy it works, its mostly educational. My questions are the ones preceding the question mark.

Comment: I think that you may be thinking about "scope" in the wrong way. If I make a really complicated function that has a lot of complicated internal variables and in the end I return one of them, do you think that javascript makes 50 copies of the function if I call it 50 times and store the returned result? That's not how it works.

Comment: @gforce301 That's not my question, I added a bit more explanation.

Comment: It is your question. Returning the reference to `pointObj` or passing it as an argument to another function call, amounts to the same thing. The reference doesn't really have "scope" in the way you are thinking about it. The identifier (the variable it is stored in) does have scope. The object is created in memory, we can have many different identifiers at different scopes referencing that single object.

Comment: @gforce301 But it's the same identifier for different objects, how does it manages this? Surely it needs some "namespace" to diferentiate them, that's why I was thinking the "namespace" or "scope" is the function imediately outside the event.

Comment: `points.forEach( point => {` That creates a closure. So it's not the "same identifier". It's an identifier with the same name inside 3 different anonymous functions (scopes). None of that has anything to do with the fact that the `Point` being created in memory doesn't care at all what identifier you use to reference it, or what scope that identifier is in. When you call this `myMap.panAndZoomToPoint(pointObj)` you didn't pass an identifier. You passed a reference to the object the identifier was pointing at, not the identifier itself.

Comment: @gforce301 Exactly! that closure is being stored as the identifiers inside it are still being used, otherwise the garbage collector would dispose them, I made an example here : http://jsfiddle.net/jks23mLb/ . It's kinda of a dumb example but it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm overwriting this variable 3 times but javascript needs to keep
>   reference to it, where will it be stored since it's outside the event
>   scope?

JS keeps it in a closure. What is a closure? You might know of `prototype` object, closure is similar but works with identifiers instead of properties.

```js
const obj = {};

obj.__proto__.someProp = "someProp";

console.log(obj.someProp); // logs "someProp"
```

Since `obj` doesn't have its own `someProp` property, JS goes up the prototype chain and finds the prop on its prototype object.

Pretty similar is going on for identifiers. You can think of functions as having a hidden `__closure__` object that stores identifiers from the upper scope. If an identifier is not found in the local scope a closest closure is checked. If it isn't found there, the closure's closure is checked.

```js
var global = "global";

function f() {
  var outer = "outer";
  function g() {
    var local = "local";
  }
};

/*

in g:
g.__localScope__ has one identifier: `local`
g.__closure__ has one identifier: `outer`
g.__closure__.__closure__ is __global_scope__ and has identifier `global`

*/
```

When you have functions that are pluck out from other functions to the upper scope

```js
function f(k) {
  return function g() {
    console.log(k);
  }
}


const g1 = f(1);
const g2 = f(2);

/*

  g1.__closure__ has identifier k that has value: 1
  g2.__closure__ also has identifier k but it has value: 2
  
  g1 can't acces k of g2 and vice versa
  
*/

g1()  // 1
g2()  // 2
```

You can see closure chain in dev tools under scope panel:
[image]

It's also good to know that modern javascript engines are very efficient are have lots of very clever optimizations.

Consider this code:

```js
function f(k) {
  const l = "l value";
  return function g() {
    debugger;
    console.log(k);
  };
}

f(1)();
```

Event though `l` is in the outer scope of `g()` function it is not listed in scope panel in dev tools:

[image]

Because this identifier is not used inside the `g()` function, Chrome JS engine V8 doesn't keep it in memory to save resources. If you change log statement to `console.log(k, l);`, both variables will be visible and accessible in dev tools:

[image]

Comment: I understand that it does not cause memory leak now, but it does use a bit more memory right? Consider these two functions : https://pastebin.com/nJ1jCRkP. Certainly storing the insideScope one will use less memory right? This would align with the last question in my post.

Comment: @Mojimi i suppose it might use a little bit more memory but every time you execute `inside` function a new string have to be created before it is logged. If you keep the string in a closure it can be reused when calling the function.

Comment: @Mojimi by the book `otherOutsideScopeStuff` should be accessible within `inside` since it is in lexical scope of `inside` but in V8 it isn't since the engine looks at the body of `inside` and can figure out that `otherOutsideScopeStuff` will never be called.

Comment: @Mojimi there are some nasty cases when a closure can leak data as the one described here: https://blog.meteor.com/an-interesting-kind-of-javascript-memory-leak-8b47d2e7f156 but most common types of memory leaks are accidental global variables, forgotten callbacks or timers and out of DOM references.

Comment: Well I guess that solves it, my main issue was that `otherOutsideScopeStuff` would remain in memory even if never called, because there can be several other `otherOutsideScopeStuff` and when you put that in a loop that create thousands of buttons with events like my original example it can get scary. Thanks! I just took some time to word better and find the right example for my question.